# How to Change Document root folder in LAMP to a mounted location (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I need to change the **document root** in LAMP, I use Ubuntu 15.

Since I want to have the same **www** folder for Linux as I have in Windows, I'll be using a mounted location.

To achieve that I ran the following command in **Terminal** (ALT+SHIFT+T -> to open Terminal):
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Inside the editor I added the following code to the file:

```
<Directory /media/my_user_name/WORK/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then I ran `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
and edited the line containing DocumentRoot to:

```
DocumentRoot /media/my_user_name/WORK/www
```

In the end I run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Now everytime I access **localhost** I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: as @ferendevelop says, you need to make sure that the apache user, has access to that directory, but also take a look in /var/log/apache2/error.log to see exactly why it is getting blocked.

Comment: Goot tip @Doon!

This is the last error I see:

`[Tue Nov 10 15:16:03.528077 2015] [core:error] [pid 7204] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:53752] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/my_user_name/WORK') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`

Comment: so based on that, make sure that the apache user (www-data i think? )  has access to all directories in that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing 3 more steps:
**1.** As suggested by @Ferendevelop I should set permission to 755 running:

```
   sudo chmod 755 /media/my_user_name/WORK/www/
```

**2** Do a *chmod +x* on the user dir by running:

```
   cd /media/
   sudo chmod +x my_user_name
```

**3** Restart Apache2 service by running:

```
   sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now it works!

*PS: Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command.

```
chmod 755 /media/my_user_name/WORK/www/
```